# Python (Windows Server) Virtualenv not recognizing Django is installed

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, windows-server-2012-r2, python-venv

My virtual environment refuses to recognize my install of Django (strangely)

I'm on Windows Server, installed Python 3.7 to a directory (`C:\Python37`) which I have `C:\Python37;C:\Python37\Scripts` in my windows Path so when using Powershell or GitBash I can use the `python` command.

if I run `where python` it shows the default install

I CD into my django project directory and run:
`python virtualenv venv` and the venv directory is created

Then I run `source venv/Scripts/activate` and it activates appropriately.

When I run `where python` it shows the exe inside the `venv` directory - which is expected and appropriate.

I run `pip install -r requirements.txt` and all my requirements install appropriately. I confirm they are installed with `pip freeze` (all installed correctly)

Once I do that I go to run `python manage.py collectstatic` (no migrations are required in this particular instance) I get an error message that Django isn't installed.

To check this, with my virtualenv still activated I enter the shell (`python`)

If I do `import django` it also says Django is not installed.

I cannot figure out what's happening here - the python version appears to be correct, the correct virtualenv is activated - but it's still not seeing the properly installed Django installation.

Thoughts? Ideas?

Comment: you are saying you are using Windows server but you have described virtualenv procedure of Linux based system

Comment: Once python is installed and the path variables are all set - it's the same process. Once you `pip install virtualenv` the process is the same except on windows you have to specify `source venv/Scripts/activate` whereas on Linux it is `source venv/bin/activate`

Comment: Does Django folder avalible under Scripts/site-packages? Django folder must be present within venv site packages.

Comment: Django installs as expected (`venv/Lib/site-packages`) - the Scripts directory is only used to activate the virtualenv (same as the `bin` in *nix)

Comment: Trying to reproduce the error but in my case no error. Only difference is that I have activated environment with venv/Scripts/activate. No source infront of the command. I am understanding the meaning of source in Windows.

Comment: Figured it out - so when I would run `python manage.py collectstatic` instead of using the activated virtualenvironment, it uses the Python installation that was explicitly stated in `.bashrc` (using an alias apparently) for this particular user account. Ugh. Thank you for your help @ANDY_VAR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth - here is the solution and explanation:

Everything works as expected as was outlined in the question - the reason that the actual python command wasn't working had to do with a line in the `.bashrc` file.

There was an alias in the `.bashrc` file to set `python` to the command `winpty C:\Python37\python`

So when the command `python manage.py collectstatic` was getting ran - it was looking at the Python executable in the Python37 directory and not the virtualenvironment Python.

This was solved by simply running the appropriate Python (e.g.)
`C:/my_project/venv/Scripts/python manage.py collectstatic`

This forced it to use the virtualenvironment python to run the command so everything worked as expected.